# Update RecyclerView with Firebase Values not working

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am working on a **Bus** app and visualized the seats of a bus in an activity using *Recyclerview* as follows

[image]

I am taking the no of **available** and **booked** seats from Firebase. What I want to do is

> update the color of the seat according to the **count** of available
> and booked seats.

**For example,** if booked seats: **2** then there should be **2** green-colored seats in the recycler view. Here is my code

**SeatsFragment.java:**

```
public class SeatsFragment extends Fragment {

public static int mCountSeat, mTotal;
public static StringBuffer mSb;
private int mSeatNo = 0;
private RecyclerView mRvViewSeats;
private ImageView mIvAvailable, mIvBooked;
private LinearLayout mLinear, mLlDack, mLlDynamic;
private List<AbstractItem> mAbstractItemsList;
private List<SeatModel> mSeatModelsItemsList;

private TextView tvAvailabe, tvBooked;

SeatAdapter adapter;

// Firebase
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference seatsRef;


public SeatsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_seats, container, false);
    tvAvailabe = view.findViewById(R.id.tvAvailableSeats);
    tvBooked = view.findViewById(R.id.tvBookedSeats);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    seatsRef = database.getReference(Common.SEATS_REFERENCE).child("2").child(Common.AVAILABLE_SEATS);
    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), seatsRef.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    seatsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            tvBooked.setText(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            tvAvailabe.setText(String.valueOf(40 - (Long.parseLong(snapshot.getValue().toString()))));



              mSeatModelsItemsList.add(new SeatModel(SeatType.AVAILABLE.BOOKED));
             initializeSeats();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    initLayouts(view);
    initializeSeats();

}

/* initialize seats */
private void initializeSeats() {

    mIvAvailable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.view_color));
    mIvBooked.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));


    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        mSeatModelsItemsList.add(new SeatModel(SeatType.BOOKED));
        mSeatModelsItemsList.add(new SeatModel(SeatType.AVAILABLE));

        int mCOLUMNS = 5;
        if (i % mCOLUMNS == 0 || i % mCOLUMNS == 4) {
            mSeatNo++;
            mAbstractItemsList.add(new EdgeItem(String.valueOf(mSeatNo)));
        } else if (i % mCOLUMNS == 1 || i % mCOLUMNS == 3) {
            mSeatNo++;
            mAbstractItemsList.add(new CenterItem(String.valueOf(mSeatNo)));
        } else {
            mAbstractItemsList.add(new EmptyItem(mSeatModelsItemsList));
        }
        GridLayoutManager mManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), mCOLUMNS);
        mRvViewSeats.setLayoutManager(mManager);
        adapter = new SeatAdapter(mSeatModelsItemsList, mAbstractItemsList, getActivity());
        mRvViewSeats.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    mSeatNo = 0;
}


private void initLayouts(View view) {
    mLinear = view.findViewById(R.id.llOffer);
    mIvAvailable = view.findViewById(R.id.ivAvailable);
    mIvBooked = view.findViewById(R.id.ivSeatFragmentBooked);
    mAbstractItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    mSeatModelsItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    mSb = new StringBuffer();
    mRvViewSeats = view.findViewById(R.id.rvSeat);
    mLlDack = view.findViewById(R.id.lvDack);

    mLlDynamic = view.findViewById(R.id.llDynamicContent);

}
 }
```

Look at the **initializeSeats()** method above. I've added two items(available and booked) to the list that is passed to the adapter. These items should be added according to the no of available and booked seats
e.g

if **booked** seats are **38**, then 38 booked items should be added to the **list**

When I try to call initializeSeats() in the **onDataChange()** it adds the correct no of seats to list but
since seats are added through loop every time seats get doubled, 1st time 40,80 and so on.

**SeatsAdapter.java:**

```
public class SeatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private List<SeatModel> mSeatItem;
private List<AbstractItem> mItems;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private Context mCtx;

public SeatAdapter(List<SeatModel> mSeatItem, List<AbstractItem> mItems, Context mCtx) {
    this.mSeatItem = mSeatItem;
    this.mItems = mItems;
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == AbstractItem.TYPE_CENTER) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_seat, parent, false);
        return new CenterViewHolder(itemView);
    } else if (viewType == AbstractItem.TYPE_EDGE) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_seat, parent, false);
        return new EdgeViewHolder(itemView);
    } else {
        View itemView = new View(mCtx);
        return new EmptyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int type = mItems.get(position).getType();
    final SeatModel seatModel = mSeatItem.get(position);

    if (type == AbstractItem.TYPE_CENTER) {

        final CenterViewHolder centerViewHolder = (CenterViewHolder)holder;

        if (seatModel.getSeatType().equals(SeatType.AVAILABLE)){
            centerViewHolder.mIvSeat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            centerViewHolder.mIvSeatBooked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    } else if (type == AbstractItem.TYPE_EDGE) {


        final EdgeViewHolder edgeViewHolder = (EdgeViewHolder) holder;


        if (seatModel.getSeatType().equals(SeatType.AVAILABLE)){
            edgeViewHolder.mIvSeat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            edgeViewHolder.mIvSeatBooked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }




    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mItems.get(position).getType();
}


/*view holder*/
private static class CenterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private ImageView mIvSeat, mIvSeatBooked;

    CenterViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mIvSeat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSeat);
        mIvSeatBooked = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSeatBooked);


    }
}

/*view holder*/
private static class EdgeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private ImageView mIvSeat, mIvSeatBooked;

    EdgeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mIvSeat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSeat);
        mIvSeatBooked = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivSeatBooked);

    }
}

/*view holder*/
private static class EmptyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    EmptyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

}


}
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciable.

Thank you.

Comment: you are not clearing mSeatModelsItemsList, it will grow with each data change, you need to clear the list before iterating and filing the list again.

Comment: @dinkar though it was a good hint but didn't solve my problem. If I clear the list every time then the no of already booked seats also gets cleared

Answer (score 1):

You just keep on adding new data in your onDataChange callback, you should clear the data when you have a new data change.
There is no need to create new adapter each time, you create your adapter once and then you just notify about changes, you should add a method in your adapter that will take a new list so you can update it in other way not only though the constructor only.

I would strongly recommend taking a look at Diff Utils It is the best way to update data inside RecyclerView and the most performant.
There are many resources on it so you can find a lot about it.
Example: https://iammert.medium.com/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00

Comment: It would be a good choice but the documentation says it was a part of support library and is no longer maintained

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html

Comment: @MuhammadHanzilah It is just moved from the support library to the androidx like every other library by google
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil#:~:text=DiffUtil%20is%20a%20utility%20class,updates%20for%20a%20RecyclerView%20Adapter.
androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil is not depracated

Comment: I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Inside your value eventListener you need to clear the list every time, and because you are not doing this so every time the new data gets added to the older ones that's why you are facing this issue.  Add this line  `mSeatModelsItemsList.clear();`

### Solution is here

```
   seatsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

     mSeatModelsItemsList.clear();// add this line


        tvBooked.setText(snapshot.getValue().toString());
        tvAvailabe.setText(String.valueOf(40 - (Long.parseLong(snapshot.getValue().toString()))));



          mSeatModelsItemsList.add(new SeatModel(SeatType.AVAILABLE.BOOKED));
         initializeSeats();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: though it was a good hint but didn't solve my problem. If I clear the list every time then the no of already booked seats also gets cleared